# How to make this edge flow?

Tags: modeling, topology, loop

While trying to create a face by poly-modeling it, I realized one of the loops wasn't flowing in the right direction, and I can't understand why this is happening. There are adjacent loops that flow on the correct direction, but I probably messed around too much on this specific loop and now the flow is gone. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

This loop is flowing on the desired direction.
[image]

This is the loop with the wrong flow, the blue arrow is the desired direction.
[image]

Comment: The "flow" is to start at one edge, and go towards the opposite edge (meaning, not connected to starting edge). Your blue arrow turns to a neighboring edge. Not that I present a good topology in the link (and that's why I don't post this as an answer; I really wished I was better at this than I am), but in principle in order to redirect the flow along your blue arrow, you would like to create edges in this fashion: https://i.imgur.com/gYfhsA6.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flow of your problematic loop is correct.

Note that you have a vertex with 5 edges there, a so called *E-pole*. I colorized it so you can see whats going on.

[image]

If you need to add another loop there then you must move the pole away in the right direction, like shown here ([image source](https://topologyguides.com/manipulating-edge-poles))

[image]

Comment: Really nice answer, IMO .. compact, clear, complete.